# arranging p numbered balls in n indistinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, balls-in-bins

let pDn the number of ways to arrange p numbered balls in n indistinguishable boxes such that p is greater than or = n and no box is empty how to calculate pDp-1.
(I tried to dissect the problem and I think it's (pDn=(p)(p-1)/2!) but I can't prove it formaly, and I'm not sure about my answer...help please)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Google on "second stirling numbers".

Comment: thanks but the balls are numbered here :\

Comment: Could you include some examples taking small values of $p$? I mean you give the actual cases which you're counting by listing them explicitly.

Comment: I tried : p=2 is 1 ,p=3 is  3 ,p=4 is 6 . But the proof must combinatorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating pDp-1 consider that there is exactly one more balls than boxes. Thus, if no box is empty, there is exaclty one box with two balls, and the rest have one exactly.

Since the boxes are indistinguishable, to count the number of ways to arrange the balls, we need only consider how many ways there are to pair two balls together.

The ways of choosing 2 balls from p is $$\frac{p!}{2!(p-2)!}$$

This can be written in the simpler form $$\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$$

Comment: thank you very much !